# Grails 2.5.0 - constraint be blank OR follow validation

Tags: grails, command-objects

I want to do something like:

```
class MyCommand {
     String name
     String data

     static constraints = {
         name blank: false, size: 3..64
         data (blank: true) || (blank: false, size: 3..64)
     }
}
```

where data is either blank or follows validation such as a size constraint if it is not blank. Is this possible to do without custom validation?

Comment: No, it's not possible without a custom validation routine.

Comment: Is there a way to run the 'data' through the regular grails email validation in custom validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be non-trivial to use other constraints within a validator constraint. The delegate of the constraints closure is a [ConstrainedPropertyBuilder](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/23461301a310956df6c8f7c49f12d189b906f55e/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/org/grails/validation/ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.java), which you can read to understand the complexity.

But that doesn't matter because the [EmailConstraint](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/23461301a310956df6c8f7c49f12d189b906f55e/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/org/grails/validation/EmailConstraint.java) uses Apache's [EmailValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html), which you can use in your validator. Here's the EmailValidator in action:

```
@Grab('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1')

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator

def emailValidator = EmailValidator.getInstance();

assert emailValidator.isValid('what.a.shame@us.elections.gov')
assert !emailValidator.isValid('an_invalid_emai_address')
```

You can use EmailValidator in your own [validator](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator

class MyCommand {
     String name
     String data

     static constraints = {
         name blank: false, size: 3..64
         data validator: {
             if(it) {
                 EmailValidator
                     .getInstance()
                     .isValid(it)
             } else { true }
         }
     }
}
```